# Format for Time

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I need to format the time like this **00h30m**.

Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: What have you tried?  There are numerous resources on the net that show the .Net formatting specifics... Such as this http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Comment: is this in a `TimeSpan`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like @Brandon's approach (and upvoted it).  An alternate approach would be to use `String.Format`.

`String.Format("{0}h{1}m", DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);`

You could encapsulate any approach in an extension method if you really wanted to.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string CustomFormat(this DateTime dt)
    {
        // Could use @Brandon's approach or whatever else here.
        return String.Format("{0}h{1}m", dt.Hour, dt.Minute);
    }
}

...

// Usage:
DateTime.Now.CustomFormat();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
.ToString("HH\\hmm\\m");
```

Note you need to escape the letters `h` and `m` with two backslashes otherwise you get a compiler error.

Comment: this should work and if you need the time formatted as 24 just replace hh with HH

Comment: @soamazing, as @Bassam said, 00h would be 24 hour notation, so just replace `hh` with `HH`

Answer (score 5):

#### Description

You should use DateTime.ToString() for that.
This will work for your.

#### Sample

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh\hmm\m");
```

Of course, replace `DateTime.Now` with your DateTime variable.

### Update

I don't know if you need 12 or 24 hour format. If you want 12 than use lowercase `hh` and if you want 24 use uppercase `HH`.

This will not work

- DateTime.ToString("hh\hmm\m")

  - will result in `Unrecognized escape sequence` so it will not compile

#### More Information

- [DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx)
- [String Format for DateTime [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: this should work and if you need the time formatted as 24 just replace hh with HH

Comment: I know it's unclear because it's 00 but I am just giving a tip to the OP just in case she needs it. I already gave you +1.

Comment: My answer covers that know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Would `DateTime.ToString("hh\hmm\m")` work for you?